# Linux bash "unexpected end of file"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos7

Добрый день,
не могу выловить причину "unexpected end of file".

Если закомментировать все циклы и условия (именно все) то все в порядке

```
#!/bin/bash
#Some setup  
ARROW=$(echo -e "\\e[1G------> ")  
CNONE=$(echo -e "\\e[00m")  
CGREEN=$(echo -e "\\e[1;32m")  
CBLUE=$(echo -e "\\e[1;34m")  
CRED=$(echo -e "\\e[1;31m")  

#Copying git changes...  
REPO_DIR="/opt/repo"  
GIT_DIR="/opt/git/blabla.git"  
BRANCH="master"  

cd /opt/git/blabla.git || exit  
while read -r oldref newref ref;  
do  
    if [ "$newref" -eq "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" ]; then continue; fi  
    if [ "$REPO_DIR" ] && [ -d "$REPO_DIR" ]; then  
       echo -e "${ARROW}${CBLUE}Deploying branch:${CNONE} ${BRANCH}"  
       cd $GIT_DIR || exit  
       sudo git --work-tree="$REPO_DIR" --git-dir="$GIT_DIR" checkout -q -f "$BRANCH"  
       break  
    fi  
done  

#Tomcat stop script  
echo -e "${CBLUE}Stopping tomcat...${CNONE}"  
if sudo service tomcat stop; then  
    echo -e "${CGREEN}Tomcat stopped${CNONE}"  
else  
    echo -e "${CRED}Tomcat stop failed${CNONE}"  
fi  

#Kill java process  
if sudo pkill -9 java; then  
    echo -e "${CGREEN}kill of JAVA successful${CNONE}"  
else  
    echo -e "${CRED}kill of JAVA failed${CNONE}"  
fi  

# Maven deploy to ROOT  
cd /opt/repo || exit  
sudo mvn -e -f pom.xml clean package -s /opt/git/settings.xml  
# Change folder access rights  
cd /opt/tomcat #|| exit  
sudo chown -R tomcat webapps  
sudo chmod -R u+rx webapps  

# Start Tomcat  
echo -e "${CBLUE}Starting tomcat...${CNONE}"  
if sudo service tomcat start; then  
    echo -e "${CGREEN}Tomcat started${CNONE}"  
else  
    echo -e "${CRED}Tomcat start failed${CNONE}"  
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

При написании Linux скрипта не был учтен тот факт, что скрипт редактировался в Notepad++ в Windows.

> Дело в том, что в Windows системах перенос строки обозначается двумя
>   символами — CR и LF, а в Linux-е только CR (возврат каретки)
>   [Взято отсюда](https://www.homeless.su/linux-tipstricks/bash-i-m-perevod-stroki-v-linux/)

Лично мне полностью решить текущую проблему (и скорее всего и будущие) помог dos2unix
Для установки необходимо:
- CentOS:

```
$ sudo yum install dos2unix
```

-Debian, Ubuntu

```
$ sudo apt-get install tofrodos
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/fromdos /usr/bin/dos2unix
```

Далее:

```
$ dos2unix source-file-path target-file-path
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, давайте более развернутые ответы, даже если отвечаете на свой вопрос

Comment: Как-то это странно. Может быть, были окончания строк CRLF? https://stackoverflow.com/q/6366530/2790048

Comment: Скорее всего вы отодвинули проблему, а не решили.

Comment: Полностью решить вопрос раз и навсегда помог dos2unix.
Скорее всего в скрипте были неверные символы переноса строки, которые и создавали проблему. Ведь сам скрипт редактировался в Notepad++ на Windows