# Синтаксическая ошибка: неожиданный конец файла

Tags: bash

```
#!/usr/sbin
if pwd
then
echo "It works"
fi
```

Скрипт в этой директории.

В начале оно ругалось на fi в конце скрипта, теперь выдаёт такую ошибку.

Comment: А что вообще этот скрипт должен делать? Я не понимаю что вы проверяете

Comment: А что за интерпретатор `/usr/sbin`  запрошен?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Linux bash "unexpected end of file"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/748509/linux-bash-unexpected-end-of-file)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Да это ж типичная проблема CRLF.

Скормите ваш файл `dos2unix`:

```
sudo apt-get install dos2unix
dos2unix ваш_файл.sh
```

Ещё можно так:

```
tr -d '\r' < input.file > output.file
```

Или так:

```
sed -i.bak 's/\r$//' ваш_файл.sh
```

Comment: Есть ещё команда для исправления знаков переноса в файле. Но, к сожалению, не помню.

Comment: @Rootware `tr -d '\r' < input.file > output.file`. Или `sed -i.bak 's/\r$//' ваш_файл.sh`.

Comment: Я думал вы это в ответ добавите, чтобы шире описано было решение проблемы кодировок DOS/UNIX. :)

Comment: @Rootware добавил)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "`pwd`" == "/home/user" ]] ;
then
 echo "i'm ready!"
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: То же самое. Печально(

Comment: Что тоже самое? :) ОС то юникс? Баш есть? Скопируйте ещё раз, это рабочий вариант

Comment: @NewView Какой там юникс, о чем вы?

Comment: @misdeed думаю, автор имел в виду Unix-подобную или POSIX-совместимую систему. Короче, что не Windows.

Comment: @NickVolynkin а вдруг всё-таки вантуз?

Comment: @misdeed тогда оно бы падало на первой строке ))

Comment: если вантуз-10, то может и не на первой. Я просто забросил вантуз, когда он еще был 7кой. Поэтому не знаю.